# Failed to resolve dockerfile - no such file or directory - docker-compose.yml

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project I am deploying using docker-compose.yml

I current have a dockerfile in both the backend folder and frontend folder. I want to run both and a database.

It is correctly building the database and fails at building the backend because of no such file or directly...

error:

```
(base) omarjandali@omarsMBPM1Max Fotos-React-Express % docker-compose up -d
[+] Running 12/12
 ⠿ mysqldb Pulled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          10.9s
   ⠿ a2a00260331c Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.3s
   ⠿ 6d8167f2fcbe Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.3s
   ⠿ 32454e9854ca Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.4s
   ⠿ 473e2917b0d5 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.5s
   ⠿ 5173f8104ec8 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.6s
   ⠿ 32e218351f9a Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             4.6s
   ⠿ fc9e1a82359a Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             5.2s
   ⠿ c602a3ea2ce7 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             5.2s
   ⠿ 3c9ea9927039 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             8.1s
   ⠿ dfb1b236c7fc Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             8.2s
   ⠿ e2ad62bd72a7 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             8.3s
[+] Building 0.1s (3/4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 => [fotos-react-express-backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 126B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [fotos-react-express-frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [fotos-react-express-backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3723136338/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysqldb:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
  
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=mysqldb
      - DB_USER=$MYSQLDB_USER
      - DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - DB_NAME=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
      - DB_PORT=$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
      - CLIENT_ORIGIN=$CLIENT_ORIGIN
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      args:
        - REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=$CLIENT_API_BASE_URL
    ports:
      - $REACT_LOCAL_PORT:$REACT_DOCKER_PORT
    networks:
      - frontend  

volumes: 
  db:

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

the following docker file is in the backend folder

dockerfile backend:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /backend
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm start
```

the following docker file is in the frontend folder

dockerfile frontend:

```
FROM node:14 as build-stage

WORKDIR /frontend
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

ARG REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL
ENV REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=$REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL

RUN npm run build
```

[image: directory]

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not failing at building the backend, it fails before that.

The dependency chain is:

1. Frontend depends on backend.
2. Backend depends on the database.
3. The database depends on nothing.

So, as the database depends on nothing, it is executed first and gets running.
Now, only frontend and backend are left and both need image building, so docker-compose checks if it will be able to build both of them by looking for the files (this is where your problem is). As last, it builds backend and then frontend.

This is where the building process starts, but it doesn't build backend and then frontend straight forward but instead docker-compose looks for the building files first:

```
[+] Building 0.1s (3/4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 => [fotos-react-express-backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 126B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [fotos-react-express-frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [fotos-react-express-backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
```

If you read carefully, it fails when resolving the Dockerfile for the frontend.

```
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3723136338/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

So the problem must be with your frontend dockerfile. Check if it is called "Dockerfile" and either rename it to match exactly that name or put the following in your docker-compose.yml:

```
build:
    context: ./frontend
    dockerfile: custom-dockerfile-name
    args:
        - REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL=$CLIENT_API_BASE_URL
```